# How do i pass a django url parameter to redirect function

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls

I'm creating a blog website and I want it to be that when a user update a post, I want to redirect them to the view page for that article.

the urls.py

```
url_patterns = [
    path('view/<str:id>/, views.viewPost, name='viewpost'), 
    path('update/<str:id>/, views.updatePost, name='updatepost') 
]
```

My problem is that, I want to be able to redirect to the viewpost when I update a post

I tried

```
return redirect('viewpost' id)
```

But it was giving me an error

Thanks for your contribution

Comment: What was the error? what did you find when researching that error?

Comment: The error I got was NoReverseMatch at /update/41

Answer (score 1):

You specify this with:

```python
id = 1425  # some id
return redirect('viewpost', id=id)
```

---

> **Note**: It might be better to use `pk` over `id`, since the `pk` field of a model always refers to the primary key,
> regardless the name of the field that is the primary key. Furthermore Python has a builtin
> [**`id(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function,
> thus by using `id` you will "shadow" the builtin.

Comment: Ok, so pk is better than id. Thanks

Comment: Alright that worked, thanks for the advice tho